# What does "accredited to you" mean in the email I received?

Tags: fees

What does "accredited to you" mean in the following sentence: 
Our first 15 minutes of consultation is at no charge, and beyond that time there will be a charge of $210 that could be accredited to you if you decided to proceed with the application?

Comment: "proceed with the application" for what? That detail might help you get a better response.

Comment: @BrianH It's for an initial consultation with a lawyer. Lawyers, unfortunately, can be very expensive.

Answer (score 9):

It means that the writer is using words that he doesn't understand. It should be "credited".

The intent is to say that the $210 that is charged for the consultation can be applied toward your future costs, if you proceed with the application.

Comment: Thus lowering my future costs by the amount of the consultation ($210) should I proceed with the application?

Comment: No, increasing your costs.

Comment: @Glen, no if the amount is credited to you, it reduces what you have to pay.

Comment: I should have been more clear. If you do not proceed, they will charge you $210. If you do proceed, they wil still charge you the $210, but might reduce the application fee by that amount.